# Continuity of compostions of functions

Tags: limits, continuity

If the composition of two functions say $g\circ f$ is continuous function at $x=c$ ($\lim_{x\to c} g\circ f(x) = g(f(c))$)then, $g$ is continuous at $f(c)$

but the function f may or may not be continuous at $x=c$ and it also possible that

$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)$ = DNE(because left hand and right hand limit are different).

is my intuition is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. For example, consider $g(x)=0.$
Then $g(f(x))=0$ as long as $f(x)$ is defined regardless of whether $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I had one more doubt,  $lim_{x \to c }g \circ f$, and it's given g is continuous everywhere, then all we need the f(x) to be defined at c right?

Comment: No, consider $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$ (round down to integer), $g(x)=x$, and $c=0$ (or any integer).

Comment: Then in my question "it's also possible the limits DNE" part was false right, I mean it's okay for discontinuity at x=c for f(x), but it should have lim as x approaches c

Comment: It depends a lot on the function $g$. If $g$ is constant it can overcome all kinds of bad properties in $f$ and $g(f(x))$ will be continuous everywhere.